# Hosting web scraping back-end and and React front-end on Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The web scraper is Node.js and Osmosis, populating a Cloud SQL db. It will run once per day, gathering a few MB of data.

The front-end will be Node.js/Express/React.

In Google Cloud, should these be separate projects or just different instances on one project? App Engine or Compute Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters: it's better to have it all in one project if possible, to have it all covered in one project.

If you want to host everything in a VM instance, analyse how many resources do you need, since you may fit [in the Free usage tier](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#freeusage). There is also the possibility of using preemptible instances, which are cheaper, but can be terminated by Compute Engine.

The advantages of running your app in Compute Engine is that, if you already have the code prepared, you can just run your code as it is. Bear in mind that, you will only be charged for a VM for its running time, but you will be charged [for its disk(s)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#disk).

If you want to go with [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/nodejs/), it's true that there is a free tier in the Standard environment and your application can scale down to 0 instances, so if there is no traffic, you won't be charged, but bear in mind that, right now, the Standard environment is in Beta and only supports the newest version of Node.js 8. In Flexible environment, there is no free tier, you always need at least one instance, but you can customise the kind of machine you use, the runtime image and you can use any version of Node.js.

As mentioned by other user, you can either go with a monolithic architecture, or one divided in [several services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine). This part is up to you but is a general recommendation to follow.

As for Cloud SQL, you are charged [for every minute that the instance is running, for the storage and the egress connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/pricing). There are some instances types that are cheaper than others, like `db-f1-micro`, but this choice will depend on your scenario. You can then configure how to connect to your instance from either [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) or [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine).

Answer (score 1):

As your usage is very little, only once per day, hosting a dedicated instance on Google Cloud Platform is not required as it will charge you even when it is not used. Go with **App Engine** which charges according to the service usage.

Make a single google project and host both back-end and front-end code. You can either host them together as a single service(Monolith Architecture) or you can keep the services isolated by deploying them as **microservices**. App Engine supports multiple microservices in a single project. You can read about that [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine)

Comment: Just to clarify, Compute Engine instances are charged when not used and App Engine is charged only when used?

Comment: Compute engine instances are your personal instances which will be running even when app traffic is zero. App Engine is managed by google and instances will become 0 when traffic is not present.