# How to deploy a Flask Backend and React Front End on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I know this may seem like an opinion-based question but I can't seem to find any answers anywhere. I'm having trouble figuring out how to deploy my flask backend and react front end on google cloud. I am using a docker-compose on my local machine but I can't seem to find a way to deploy that on Google Cloud.

My question is, is there a way to deploy them using a docker-compose file using Cloud Build and Cloud Run? Or do I have to create two different Cloud Run instances to run the frontend and backend? Or is it better to create a VM instance and run the docker-compose container on there (and how would one even do this)? I am very new to deployment so any help is appreciated.

For reference, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542780/hosting-web-scraping-back-end-and-and-react-front-end-on-google-cloud) but it didn't exactly answer my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is still not relevant to Stack overflow. There are several ways to deploy your solution to Google Cloud. The majority of these require some re-architecting. The simplest solution as it requires almost no changes would be to create a Compute Engine VM with Docker and Docker Compose and deploy your existing solution as-is. You would also need to program a firewall to expose your app to others. A good solution would be to combine your front-end and back-end (I assume there's a single process) into a single process in a single container and deploy this to Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0):

You use docker-compose for multi-container applications. In your case it wouldn't make much sense.

You have a python backend. You can containerize it and deploy to Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, App Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine or even on a Compute Engine VM. In my opinion the most convenient option would be Cloud Run.

If your React frontend is a Single Page App, it communicates with your python backend with HTTP requests. You build the HTML/CSS/JS files and host them somewhere, like a Cloud Storage bucket or Cloud CDN.